# Why doesn´t my Outlook rule work more then once?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, vba, exchange

I´ve recently migrated my email to an exchangeserver, with my previous email set as a forward to my current one.
I´m using outlook 2010 and Samsung galaxy s5.

First problem at hand: Some E-mails coming from the forwarded email gets corrupted as to not show the scandinavic letters, they do however seem to turn out fine in the phone.
Second problem: I´ve written a macro to autocorrect all of the corrupt letters, and it works on my workmail which isn´t connected to an exchangeserver, but when I try to run it on the exchange server mail it only works once when I´ve restarded my computer and then it doesn´t.

the script goes as follows:

```
    Sub testing(MyMail As MailItem)
     MyMail.HTMLBody = Replace(MyMail.HTMLBody, "", "")
     MyMail.Save
    End Sub
```

Any leads as to what the flippety flopp to do?